# For an SVG element <text>, how do I align from the top left of the text block and not from the bottom left?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to get an svg `<text>` element inside a `<rect>` element. I know the coordinates of that element, but when I give the coordinates to `<text>`, it seems that the coordinate "point" that's being translated is the bottom left of that block of text.

My question is, how do I programmatically "know" the height of the text so I can offset that into my coordinates? I will not always have a pixel value or be able to trial and error to compensate for the font size. Is there even a better way to do this?

Here's a sample code so you can test for yourself:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <svg width={200} height={200}>
        <rect width={200} height={200} fill="pink"></rect>
        <rect x="0" y="100" height="100" width="100" fill="pink"></rect>
        <text x="0" y="50">Hello world should be inside the rectangle</text>
        <text x="0" y="100" fontSize="2em">
          Hello world.
        </text>
      </svg>

</body>

</html>
```

Here's what I'm getting:
[image]

And here's what I was expecting:
[image]

Thank you :)

Comment: Call getBBox on the text element

Comment: Use `dominant-baseline="hanging"` for the text

Comment: @enxaneta don't you want to post an answer so I can accept it? That worked beautifully, thanks